# Show/Hide div issue in Jquery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have copied Jquery code from another website and “Link one” is working fine. When I press on it, a popup div appear and when I click outside of the div it’s gone (which is fine). But “Link Two and Three popup divs” are not appear/disappear properly. Can you please enhance code? Please check out below link (what I have done so far)

http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/SNCtu/

Also please make sure, at a time only one div appear even I press “Link Two” or “Link Three”

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this much shorter demo** http://jsfiddle.net/vERmV/

Rest hope it fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$(function() {
    $('#hidden1,#hidden2,#hidden3').hide().click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".cart-buttom1,.cart-buttom2,.cart-buttom3").click(function(e) {

        var id = $(this).attr('class').replace(/cart-buttom/, '');

        $('.popup').hide()
        $('#hidden' + id).animate({
            opacity: "toggle"
        });

        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#hidden1,#hidden2,#hidden3').fadeOut();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(function() {
    $('#hidden1').hide().click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("a[class^='cart-buttom']").click(function(e) {
        var $cls = $(this).data('class');
        $("[id^='hidden']").not('#' + $cls).fadeOut();
        $('#' + $cls).animate({
            opacity: "toggle"
        });
        $("#shopping-cart").animate({
            "height": "toggle"
        }, {
            duration: 550
        });
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#hidden1').fadeOut();
        $('#hidden2').fadeOut();
        $('#hidden3').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

I have added a data attribute to the anchors that stores the corresponding div id's

[CHECK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/SNCtu/1/)

Comment: Yo bru, + 1 jsut another think, chain rest of the stuff, you will be rockin after that `:)`

Comment: Heh, No worries, please excuse my spell mistakes man, `:)` lol typing fast :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is is more simple demo of what you are looking for .

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5NEu3/273

http://jsfiddle.net/5NEu3/276/

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="#content1">Show content 1</a>
    <a href="#content2">Show content 2</a>
    <a href="#content3">Show content 3</a>
</div>

<div id="content1" class="toggle" style="display:none">show the stuff1</div>
<div id="content2" class="toggle" style="display:none">show the stuff2</div>
<div id="content3" class="toggle" style="display:none">show the stuff3</div>

//In Document.Ready
$("#nav a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".toggle").fadeOut();
    var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
    $(toShow).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Yo paste your code as well, sometime fiddle is down for maintenance hence its worth while to add the code in the post,  **+1** anyways `:))`

Answer (score 0):

When you bind click event to the a tag of class cart-buttom with -> $("a.cart-buttom").click
you only give your specified event (which is appear/disappear as you explained) only to the class cart-buttom, but not cart-buttom2 or cart-buttom3.

Thus, you could guess from this explanation that identifiers for classes in html, having any characters as suffixes would turn into a completely different class. In order to bind a click event also for them, you can define different click events for cart-buttom2, and cart-buttom3 classes separately. There are of course wiser ways to do such a thing.

Comment: Can you please help me as i am not good in Jquery? I really appreciate if you can write code in jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SNCtu/2/, Something like this, as I said that's not an elite solution for this kind of a thing. To start with, "class" attributes are subject to be used for the tags that share the same characteristics, like same having same css, functioning in the same way etc. Thus, for such a purpose that you demand, "id" is more proper. A wiser solution would be writing a function that takes an id for your elements that has a click event, and does whatever you like as you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/sm7w5/ **I've written something fast just to give an idea, might not be complete**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hff5W/1/ and also http://jsfiddle.net/hff5W/3 for you to get the idea first then get rid of redundant code